# Any way to export some html/css to an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, pdf-generation, tcpdf

Basically I have an `<ul>` list with a few `<li>` items styled with CSS that may change proprieties ( jquery click adds a class with different background).

I'm using TCPDF library to generate PDFs and need to add that `<ul>` to the PDF but TCPDF doesn't yet support advanced CSS styling.

So is there a way to generate an image, a snapshot of that `<ul>`? Then I'd only need to include it in the PDF.

Thanks!

Comment: does it accept in-line styling ?

Comment: If it's a one-off, why not just take a screenshot?

Comment: @thirtydot by "generate" I don't think it means one off lol but good point :)

Comment: No, it needs to be generated multiple times... it's some kind of report. And @Val I tried to do that, but didn't work.

Comment: @alex http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/Default.aspx here is a link that this ppl have done something similar, now I have no idea how they have done it, but it shows that it is possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(I didn't read your question particularly well before)*

Why not just switch to a better PDF generator?

If you can run custom software on your server, I heavily recommend [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

Otherwise, use [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

---

You could stick with TCPDF and use [wkhtmltoimage](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) to make a screenshot of your `ul`. But, that seems a bit crazy. To run wkhtmltoimage, you need to be able to run custom software, and if you can do that, you might as well just switch to wkhtmltopdf. If you can't run custom software - it's not really possible to render HTML/CSS with pure PHP, so you'll have to come up with something else.

Comment: Yeah I've read about wkhtmltopdf but for the moment I don't have a server with root access. Dompdf looks like a good alternative, thanks!